# ECONNREFUSED error when loading a TensorFlow frozen model from node.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I was trying to load a TensorFlow fronzen model from a url that points to not existing resource to test my code robustness. However, even though I have set a `catch`, I am not able to manage a `ECONNREFUSED` that is raised internally by the function `tf.loadFrozenModel`.

Is there any possible mitigation to this issue? This is for me a critical problem, since it stops the execution of nodejs.

Here is the code where the error is generated.

```
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");

class TFModel {
    ...

    loadFzModel(modelUrl, modelWeigths) {
        return tf.loadFrozenModel(modelUrl, modelWeigths)
            .then((mod) => {
                this.arch = mod;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error downloading the model!");
            });
    }

    ...
}
```

Here instead are the errors I am getting:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: http://localhost:30000/webModel/tensorflowjs_model.pb not found. FetchError: request to http://localhost:30000/webModel/tensorflowjs_model.pb failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30000
at BrowserHTTPRequest.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/browser_http.js:128:31)
at step (.../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/browser_http.js:32:23)
at Object.throw (.../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/browser_http.js:13:53)
at rejected (.../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/browser_http.js:5:65)
at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

(node:23291) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23291) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Note**: the code works if `modelUrl` and `modelWeights` are valid url pointing to existing resources.

**Node-2**: the code is executed as part of a custom block for [Node-Red](https://nodered.org/).

Comment: Could you show us the error message, the exact line it occurs and which version of tfjs you are using?

Comment: Looks like the Exception doesn't get passed up to your call. You could open up a issue on the tfjs github page

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Sure, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find any other solution you can catch the error on the top level like this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

In there you can get more specific to only catch your specific error.

Comment: I am sorry, but unfortunately this method does not work for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is in the process of being addressed at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/pull/1455.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Actually this is the pull request that has been created after I created an issue on their repository.